# Is correct to use the past perfect continuous after the present perfect when the sentences are somehow connected?

Tags: present-perfect, past-perfect-continuous

could you tell me if it is correct to use the past perfect continuous after the present perfect the sentences are somehow connected? For example:

> I have finally moved from the city. **I had been living** there for five years.

If it's not correct and natural, could you tell me what tense would you use after the present perfect to say that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, past perfect continuous will not be used here.

In order to use past perfect continuous, you have to **review** something happened **before** a time in the past, in other words, the past of past. Thus, normally you can decide whether you should use past perfect continuous by finding past tense in the sentence. The following situation, for example, can use the past perfect continuous:

> Before I **moved** out of my hometown, I **had been** shinning shoes for a living.

(Notice a past tense is used to indicate I'm receiving something happened in the past before the past when I left my hometown.)

So, what I would recommend to make the sentence syntactically correct is the following:

> I finally moved from the city. I had been living there for five years.

Or:

> I have finally moved from the city. I lived there for five years.

Hope it helps, if there are any errors, please correct me, cause I'm still an ESL.